# Blender particles not rendering correctly, any ideas on what's wrong?

Tags: blender

I'm fairly new to blender, and I just made my first animation, however the particles glitch out and bunch up on the spawning plane for a while then all drop at once and glitch out. This only happens when I render it, any ideas on how to fix it? [Here's a video](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/869803909953245246/1039003783054774343/2022-11-06_20-49-08.mp4)

I have tried to decrease the number of particles and close all my apps, but it doesn't work. I thought it would be a clear smooth drop and it falls out of frame with a constant flow of cylinders.